# How can I override an existing custom CSS rule for a specific page

Tags: css

I know how to add a CSS rule for a specific post, using the post-id. However I already have a custom CSS rule for modifying an element and now I want to hide that element for a specific post.

```
/* Hide likes on post 650 */
.post-id-650 #post-meta-likes{ 
   display: none; 
}
```

The above line doesn't work, even if I place it at the top of the custom CSS form. It only works if I remove the CSS rules for the #post-meta-likes class further down the form.

*Edit:* Actually, the line doesn't work at all. I thought it did, but it doesn't... So even if it is the only custom CSS rule, it doesn't hide the element on the page. So, back to the basic question: Is this the correct rule to hide an element on a specific Wordpress page?

Comment: May be you need to be more specific (increase specificity) or try adding `!important` ( Not recommended)

Comment: Adding the !important parameter didn't work, I tried that. How can I be more specific?

Comment: Like adding extra class/id/tag, for example `body.post .post-id-650 #post-meta-likes`

Comment: Take a look in the browser's inspector to look if your rule is applied and what rule is overriding it. That will give you the clue for a solution.

Comment: Anyway this is entirely CSS based question which is considered off-topic here.

Comment: Actually, the line doesn't work at all. I thought it did, but it doesn't... So even if it is the only custom CSS rule, it doesn't hide the element on the page. So, back to the basic question: Is this the correct rule to hide an element on a specific Wordpress page?

Comment: @cjbj, just to be honest, the dudes on these forums are more than able to look at your page online and use developer tools to then tell you what is wrong with your wordpress css rule.  feel free to post a link and location.